# Github Action create a new file for each value in an array

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm trying to create a new file for each value in an array:

This is what I have so far and it successfully creates a file based on a GET and pushes it into my repo. Now I would like it to do it for multiple files at once. How do I get it to iterate over the result of myRequest if it were an array and create a file for each value and then finally commit and push them all?

```
name: Manual workflow
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  makefiles:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Getting
      uses: fjogeleit/http-request-action@master
      id: myRequest
      with:
        url: 'https://domain/api/file'
        method: 'GET'
    - name: Show File
      run: echo ${{ steps.myRequest.outputs.response }}
    - name: Create A File
      uses: 1arp/create-a-file-action@0.2
      with:
        path: 'src'
        file: 'foo.bar'
        content: ${{steps.myRequest.outputs.response}}
    - name: final commit
      uses: zwaldowski/git-commit-action@v1
      id: git_commit
    - name: show
      run: echo "${{ steps.git_commit.outputs.sha }}"
```

The output of my request is an encoded JSON:

```
[
{
  title: "foo",
  body: "bar"
},
{
  title: "foo",
  body: "bar"
},
{
  title: "foo",
  body: "bar"
}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

If your response is an Array, you can pass it to next step using `toJson`, `fromJSON`.
This example should be helpful:

```
name: build
on: push
jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      matrix: ${{ steps.set-matrix.outputs.matrix }}
    steps:
      - id: set-matrix
      run: |
        JSON=$(cat ./your.json)
        echo "::set-output name=matrix::${JSON//'%'/'%25'}"

  job2:
    needs: job1
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix: ${{fromJSON(needs.job1.outputs.matrix)}}
    steps:
      - run: build
```

I don't know exact format of your file and how those files are written down - but as long as you can make Array out of them, it should be easy to use `toJSON` to get proper output format.

One way is do use `jq` to generate JSON in bash, or even better make your `https://domain/api/file` script to generate JSON as an output format - easiest solution imho.

If you don't want to use it directly into `matrix`, you can read it also like this:

```
job2:
    needs: job1
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: |
         echo "${{ fromJSON(needs.job1.outputs.matrix).jsonKey}}"
```

For bash iterations, use a bash syntax:

```
for i in "${array[@]}"
do: 
done
```

Comment: `https://domain/api/file script to generate JSON as an output format` it already does so I should just be good to go from your example?

Comment: Well in my example it will run everything in matrix - in parallel, not sure if that's what you need - but that's most often the case :)
If you want to just iterate over those values in bash, you man need to modify job2 code a bit. Then I would recommend going with `jq` as I mentioned in my answer - you get `fromJSON` into variable and then use `jq` to read it, iterate over arrays etc...

Comment: I updated my example a bit to show you also how to access value directly

Comment: Would it be too much to ask you to put your code into my example? Unfortunately not familiar with bash. `- name: Show File` should where it starts to do stuff with each array. So right now it puts the entire array into 1 file, can you show how to split up each value of the array into its own file.